# Cómo traducir "rendering"

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

En el contexto del diseño gráfico, es común encontrar la palabra `render`, e inclusive, en la wikipedia en español existe [una página](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renderizaci%C3%B3n) que trata el tema.

Aún así, no existe una palabra oficial para referirse al proceso de `renderizado`, se puede traducir como `generación de contenido multimedia`, `representación`, `interpretación`.

Creo que la traducción `generación de contenido multimedia` es la más correcta, existe alguna traducción (si es posible en una sola palabra) que se adecue mejor al termino en español en el contexto de creación de imágenes?

Creo que es incorrecto utilizar la palabra `render`, pues en español significa una cosa [completamente distinta](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=fOWEp88t3DXX2tTSOMuy).

Comment: Si la palabra *render* se termina adaptando al español, se convertirá en *rénder*; por tanto, es una palabra distinta de la que enlazas. Además, una es un sustantivo y la otra, un verbo que ha caído en desuso. No veo posibilidad de error. Eso sí: según la RAE, tanto *renderizar* como *render* deberían escribirse entre comillas o en cursiva, por ser extranjerismos.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Render" y "Renderizar" (renderización, renderizado, etc...) parecen términos correctos en español. Por los links que aportas en la pregunta, parece que quienes se dedican al diseño 3D conocen y usan estos términos, y dado que no hay equivalentes cómodos en el español (representar, reproducir?) usan los anglosajones.

Cierto que "renderizar"  o "renderización" no tienen todavía entrada en el DRAE con los significados que entendemos, pero eso es sólo porque la RAE no se ha puesto al día todavía con el uso de estas palabras. [Otras fuentes](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/renderizacion-2203/) explican:

> ["render"] refiere al proceso de generar una imagen, a veces puede equivaler a **modelado**, pero en el sentido más habitual se suele adaptar como **renderizado** o **renderización** (y el verbo es **renderizar**).

Creo que intentar traducir el término como *modelado, representar o reproducir* puede causar más confusión para los usuarios que ya están habituados al término anglosajón.

Comment: La apreciación de @Gorpik del comentario de arriba me parece interesante añadirla. Si se incorpora "render" al DRAE, probablemente lo acentúen a "rénder".

Comment: También podemos entenderlo como **sintetizar** una imagen a partir de un modelo, generalmente en 3D. *Representar o modelar* tampoco me parecen tan malas opciones.

Answer (score 3):

En el contexto del diseño gráfico `renderizar` es producir el contenido utilizable.

En las computadoras el proceso de `renderizar` es el de dibujar en la pantalla (o mas concretamente dicho producir contenido utilizable). Cada intervalo de tiempo el sistema operativo `renderiza` (dibuja) contenido en la pantalla para nuestra visualización.

La connotación de `interpretar` no la he visto hasta ahora, sin embargo, dependiendo del contexto puede ser traducida como `generación de contenido multimedia` como dices, `dibujar` o `redibujar`.

Comment: Interesante aportación lo de "interpretar" y "dibujar". En el Chrome Dev Tools (herramienta para desarrolladores web, digamos) se usa "paint" en el sentido que (creo) se entiende "render".

Answer (score 1):

En español hay palabras más precisas para expresar los distintos usos de *render* en inglés.

En general *render* da la idea de algo que se obtiene (produce) al terminar un proceso. En español eso va implícito en los verbos con que podemos traducirlo.

A mí tampoco me gusta que se use como barbarismo, por que se acaba hablando en spanglish como Tin-Tan en su papel pachuco.

Quien no puede traducir esos términos al español, evidencia que no está entendiendo su significado y se exhibe como iletrado.

La traducción más adecuada depende del contexto.

En el caso de las imágenes generadas por computadora. Se puede decir: 
"la imagen *generada*".
O si se habla de alguna técnica para transformarla, simplemente 
"la imagen *transformada*"

Incluso podrías usar *rendir* que en este contexto significa entregar.
Por ejemplo:

"el método de interpolación *rinde* una imagen más suave".

aunque podrías igualmente decir *genera*, *da* o *produce*.

En otros casos se puede decir *terminado*, *acabado*.

"La imagen tiene un *acabado* más luminoso".

En el contexto de la arquitectura, el vocablo inglés *render* significa *acabado* o *los acabados*. En el contexto del procesamiento de imágenes a veces se podría traducir de la misma manera.

"Esa animación tiene buen acabado"

También podrías hablar de la *imagen procesada*.

Incluso se puede hablar de *representación*, *producto*, *imagen producida* o simplemente *imagen*

"esa es la *imagen* teselada"

Comment: La palabra `imagen` no lleva tilde, podrías corregirla en los lugares en que la pusiste con tilde? (En algunos lugares la escribiste bien, en otros la escribiste con tilde)

Comment: "Quien no puede traducir esos términos [...] se exhibe como iletrado." Innecesariamente agresivo